# Spree Deface: how to insert a column into a table?

Tags: spree, deface

I need to add a column to a table in Spree's Admin backend. There is a data-hook on each `<tr>`.

So in theory I can `insert_top` a `<td>` on each row (and also insert a `<th>` in the `<thead>` and a `<col>` in the `<colgroup>`).

Is this the best way, or is there a better way?

Answer (score 0):

This is fairly easy to achieve using a few small files with the new .deface DSL. Eg with HAML (assuming Spree::Order has a custom attribute called distributor)

Header:

```
/ insert_top "[data-hook='admin_orders_index_headers']" 
%th
  Distributor
```

Rows:

```
/ insert_top "[data-hook='admin_orders_index_rows']"
%td.align-center
  = order.distributor.name
```

If you want to alter the column widths, it's often easier just to overwrite the colgroup:

```
/ replace_contents "table#listing_orders colgroup" 
%col{style: "width: 10%"}
...etc
```